# Having trouble interpreting this C++ code

Tags: c++, struct, operator-overloading, inline

**Background about code posted:** PayRoll is the name of the class. personSalary is a double type variable, and personAge is an integer type variable. The code given is sorting a list by age or by the salary.

```
struct less_than_salary
    {
        inline bool operator() (const PayRoll& struct1, const PayRoll& struct2)
        {
        return (struct1.personSalary < struct2.personSalary);
        }
    };

struct less_than_age
    {
        inline bool operator() (const PayRoll& struct1, const PayRoll& struct2)
        {
        return (struct1.personAge < struct2.personAge);
        }
    };
```

I would like some help understanding this section of the given code. I've tried reading what **struct** is used for and from what I understand, it basically operates as a class and allows you to work with many types of variables at one time. If I'm wrong, what exactly is a struct used for in this context?
Also, I would appreciate it if someone explained what "inline bool operator()" was doing because I've never seen that before and I could not understand by reading the textbook.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try googling for "functor".

Comment: Do you mean you do not understand the concept of operator-overloading? `operator()` allows an instance of the class to react to a *function-call* operator.

Comment: Yes that was my issue, I'm having a hard time understanding operator-overloading.

Comment: @ss1111 If this is homework, you can earn bonus points for yelling at your instructor about the redundant use of `inline` in this context.

Comment: I'll be sure to yell at my professor! How would you write this if you were to eliminate the redundancy? I'm just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A struct like this can be used in the STL function `sort`, which is avaliable in data structures such as `std::list`.

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::list<int> example = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};

    struct {
        bool operator()( const int lhs, const int rhs) {
            return lhs < rhs;
        }
    } compare_list;

    example.sort(compare_list);

    for(auto &i : example) {
        std::cout<<i<<" ";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

To understand how this works, consider the following:

```
//..
testS(compare_list);
//..

template <typename T>
void testS(T t) {
    std::cout<< t(4,5) << "\n";
    std::cout<< t(5,4) << "\n";
}
```

The output would be

```
1
0
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for the explanation! I understand how the code is working now! I had one more question. So _bool operator()_ is basically taking in lhs and rhs making them act as if they were _bool_ correct? Otherwise you would get an error saying "operator== not defined"?

Comment: Yes, our `compar_list` struct implements the `()` operator. The `()` operator makes this a functor, which means it can be called like a function.
It takes in two arguments and returns the _boolean_ result of _lhs < rhs_. If my answer helped you, mark it as solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Both structs are implementations of a so-called "functor".    Given usage like

```
 PayRoll x;
 PayRoll y
    // initialise x and y

 less_than_salary f;

 if (f(x,y))    // this calls less_than_salary::operator()(x,y)
     std::cout << "X has lower salary than Y\n";
 else
     std::cout << "X has higher salary than Y\n";
```

Also, given an array of `PayRoll`, it is possible to sort

```
 PayRoll a[20];

 //   initialise elements of a

 less_than_salary f;
 std::sort(a, a+20, f);   // will sort in order of ascending salary

 std::sort(a, a+20, less_than_salary());  // does same as preceding two lines
```

Standard containers (`std::vector<PayRoll>`, etc) can also be used.

`less_than_age` allows doing essentially the same thing, but using age rather tnan salary as a sort criterion.

There is no function overloading as such here.  Both struct types provide an `operator()`, but that is not overloading.

Comment: +1 Thank you! Could you elaborate on why there is no function overloading? I still do not quite understand, I'm trying to learn as much as possible.

Comment: Function overloading is providing functions with the same name, in the same scope, that accept different argument types.    What you're doing is providing two struct types, each of which has an `operator()` with the same argument types.    Each struct type is a different scope.